# Reading files from a directory and sending files to another class

Tags: java, arrays, file, class

I have two classes that I'm working with, the first which just finds the file and sends it to the second class, which does the work I need it to do.

So far, I've only managed to get the first class to read through a directory and print the names of the files. This is the code I use to see the names:

```
    File folder = new File("data\\");
    File[] listFiles = folder.listFiles();

    for (File file : listFiles){
        if (file.isFile()){
        System.out.println(file);
        }
    }
```

However, i need to send the files over to the other class to read through. Up until now, I was doing

```
    Grader.getFileInfo("data\\studentSubmissionA.txt");
    Grader.teacherFiles("data\\TeacherListA.txt");
```

to send the file information over, but this isn't as convienient as using the array to go through the entire directory.

However, I don't know how to get it to send the files over to the other class one by one in order for the class to do its work.

I've been browsing the internet for hours and only found things which list the file names and that's not what I need to do. I actually need to send the files and their content over to the next class.

Is there any way to actually do this? And how would i go about doing it?

I just want to use an arraylist if possible, so no try/catch, or BufferedReader if possible since I've been using scanner.

What I'm trying to say is that instead of printing the names of the files in the directory, as the array does now, I would like it to iterate through and send the information in the files to the second class as the Grader.getFileInfo() calls do.

Comment: *"finds the file and sends it to the second class,.."*  By 'file' DYM a Java based `File` or the actual content of the file?

Comment: Some clarification would be good... are you not wanting to replace System.out.println(file);  with Method(file) ??

Comment: @AndrewThompson I mean the actual content of the file.

Comment: @Kairan No, not really because then I still have to list all the files in the folder. I want the array to go through automatically and send the files over.

Comment: The content of one `File` might be passed in a `byte[]`.  The content of many files might be passed in a `byte[][]`.  Having said that, it seems to me that it would be better to pass a `File[]` to the second class, and have the 2nd class read the `byte[]` of each file.  That way, the called class can identify which part of data produced a specific result.

Comment: @AndrewThompson How would I go about doing that? And I only really want an array in the first class, not the second. Is that possible?

Comment: Are you just reading text from the input files?

Comment: @Kairan Yes, pretty much. There are math equations in the .txt files but they're still strings.